# App Services - Cost Optimization recommendations

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

Does Enable Auto Scaling in App Services help reduce the cost?
If Yes, how do i identify if a App services have Auto Scaling Enabled or not?

what are other different ways to optimize App services cost other Reserved Instances/Savings Plan purchases at enterprise level..

please help me with logics to identify this optimization recommendations

this is new for us; so would like to explore

Comment: Hi @Sdoshi13, Please check [here](https://i.imgur.com/pY7dVfV.png) - Navigate to the Azure Portal<Go to the App Service you want to check<In the left menu, under **Settings** , select **Scale out (App Service Plan)**.

(or) Use the Azure CLI to check the autoscale settings - `az monitor autoscale show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --resource <app-service-plan-name>
`

Answer (score 0):

> Does Enable Auto Scaling in App Services help reduce the cost? If Yes, how do i identify if a App services have Auto Scaling Enabled or not?

- Enabling Auto Scaling in App Service can help optimize costs by automatically adjusting the number of instances based on the demand.

By this you will have enough instances to handle the load during peak times and can scale down during periods of lower demand, helping you avoid over-provisioning and reduce costs.

- Here, first your app service must be in premium then only you can opt for the auto scaling.
  `Azure portal<App Service<Scale out (App Service Plan)<you can see the Auto Scale settings`

[image]

You can also update by using Azure CLI.

**cmd:**
`az appservice plan update --name <APP_SERVICE_PLAN> --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> --elastic-scale true --max-elastic-worker-count <YOUR_MAX_BURST>`

[image]

*Refer this Documents:*

- [Enable automatic scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-cli#enable-automatic-scaling).
- [Premium plan settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#plan-and-sku-settings)